# How to correctly implement a simple search functionality with ajax in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to code a simple search functionality for learning purposes, but I am failing to make it work.

What I want for now is simply to pass some data(to a controller function) in a blade view with ajax and then display this data in another view via the same controller function.

What I currently have is this :

Routes :

```
Route::get('/search-results', 'HomeController@search')->name('search');
```

`search` in `HomeController` :

```
 public function search(Request $request){
        $data = $request->data;
        return view('search-results')->with('data',$data);
    }
```

the `search-results` view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
       <h1>{{$data}}</h1>
    @endsection
```

And finally the ajax :

```
var data = "success";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search-results',
            type: "get",
            data: {data : data},
            success: function(response){
                if(data == "success")
                    console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

Can someone help me make this work? I am not sure what am I doing wrong...

Comment: Are you trying to reload the page with the search results showing, or update the page you are on without reloading the whole thing / navigating?

Comment: @arbuthnott  My ajax is on one page and after a button click the ajax is executed and then i want to show the results on another page - in my case search-results. My ajax is in the "home" view

Comment: in that case, you should really use something like an html form and post it to your search url. ajax is for the purpose of staying on the same page while fetching results from the server. (I can provide an answer along those lines in a bit if no similar answers show up).

Comment: @arbuthnott yes, you are absolutely right. I just did it with forms and it is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `JsonResponse` object to easy use data in JavaScript

Action:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $data = $request->data;

    return new JsonResponse(compact('data'));
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/search",
    type: "get",
    data: {data : data},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX call is asynchronous therefore you can make a call and return the results in a separate form. If you want to show your results in a separate form, i advise that you submit the form and then return the view with your data `return view('search-results')->with('data',$data);` or if you stick to an an ajax call, you return a response which will be sent to the form where the data was submitted from `return response()->json(["data" => $data]);`

Answer (score 0):

Routes :

```
Route::get('/search-results', 'HomeController@search')->name('search');
```

`search` in `HomeController` :

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $result = [];
    $result['data'] = $request->data;
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

the `search-results` view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
   <h1 class="header"></h1>
@endsection
```

Ajax call :

```
var data = "success";
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ route('search') }}",
  type: "get",
  data: {'data' : data},
  success: function(response){
        if(response.data == "success")
           console.log(response.data);
           $('.header').text(response.data);
        }
});
```

Hope it's help you!!!